# Voice recognition (speech to text - STT cordova plugin)

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2, voice-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm looking for **speech recognition** in **Ionic2** framework with cordova **plugin**.

If it can be implemented, could you gently provide an example of code (.html and .ts)?

I found this, but was for Ionic1: http://devgirl.org/2016/01/08/speaking-with-cordova/ and i can't adapt the code for Ionic2.

I really appreciate any help you can provide, and sorry for my little english.

Comment: Check out this link - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_Speech_Recognizer

Comment: This is for ionic :( 
How can I convert the code to ionic 2?

Comment: Do understand. But exactly is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Ionic 2 use html page with ts file for logic, Ionic use html page with js for logic, i don't know how to convert these files for running in an Ionic 2 environment..
I'm quite new in Ionic 2, and don't have so much flexibilities.

Comment: As i understood from this link - https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html .ts file is also jus like .js file

Comment: So, based on that, i can use .js just like .ts file, with no modifications or code adapter? Thx you

Comment: Thats what the link says. But any specific reason to go for Ionic 2? Guess its still in beta

Comment: Yeah, still in beta for now, but nearly to a stable release.
Why ionic2? It's beautiful, fast programming and quite simple.
Since i'm new to Ionic, i preferred to learn the future generation of this language.
I have to develop a project (for my Master's degree) that will be finished in December (maybe), and I think Ionic2 will be no longer in beta for that moment. :)

Comment: All the very best. Hope to see you soon. Happy coding. Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Source: https://github.com/macdonst/SpeechRecognitionPlugin.

Using command line, add this plugin to your Ionic2 project:

```
cd Your_Project_Root_Folder
```

Since iOS 10 it's mandatory to add a `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` in the info.plist to access the microphone.

To add this entry you can pass the `MICROPHONE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION` variable on plugin install.

```
ionic plugin add https://github.com/macdonst/SpeechRecognitionPlugin --variable MICROPHONE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="your usage message"
```

On iOS 10 and greater it uses the native SFSpeechRecognizer (same as Siri).
On iOS 9 and older it uses iSpeech SDK, an API key is required, get one on https://www.ispeech.org/, it's free. To provide the key, add this preference inside the config.xml

```
<preference name="apiKey" value="yourApiKeyHere" />
```

Add declaration at the beginning of your **.ts** file, just after import, before class definition:

```
declare const SpeechRecognition: any;
```

Then, in your class:

```
recognition: any;

constructor() {}

SpeechToText() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.recognition = new SpeechRecognition(); 
        this.recognition.lang = 'en-US';
        this.recognition.onnomatch = (event => {
            console.log('No match found.');
        });
        this.recognition.onerror = (event => {
            console.log('Error happens.');
        });
        this.recognition.onresult = (event => {
            if (event.results.length > 0) {
                console.log('Output STT: ', event.results[0][0].transcript);            
            }
        });     
        this.recognition.start();
    });
}
```

iSpeech supported languages are:
*English (Canada) (en-CA) English (United States) (en-US) Spanish (Spain) (es-ES) French (France) (fr-FR) Italian (Italy) (it-IT) Polish (Poland) (pl-PL) Portuguese (Portugal) (pt-PT)*

ps: For iOS 10 error kAFAssistantErrorDomain or if you have to wait for results, check [this](https://github.com/macdonst/SpeechRecognitionPlugin/issues/88).

**Done!**

edit: tested on Ionic v3.0.1 (2017-04-06) and works fine :)

Comment: do you have a working example of this code? i'm getting a "speech regcognition not defined" error

Comment: This code worked fine on beta-ionic2. After the RC release, i don't know.
I'm upgrading the project, but for now, not the STT part.
Stuck with sqlite problem...

Comment: @aheigins I updated the project to ionic2 RC1 and works as expected.
The code is exactly that, no change needed.

Comment: Fixed It https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/something-different-in-rc3-4-vs-rc2-in-declaration/73590/5  add in android.json and config.xml, works in device!!

Answer (score 1):

I use this AngularJS directive:

[ng-speech-recognition](https://github.com/Devniz/ng-speech-recognition)

Comment: How to use with Ionic 2?